# « Tout à coup » ou « Tout d'un coup » ?

Tags: expressions, usage

Est-ce correct de dire *tout d'un coup* lorsqu'un évènement survient ?

Ne devrait-on pas plutôt employer *tout à coup* ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

L'expression correcte à utiliser est *tout à coup* lorsque l'on veut décrire quelque chose qui survient soudainement.

*Tout d'un coup* signifie que quelque chose survient en un seul coup, en une seule fois.

[Les clefs du français pratique](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_t&page=9XcTOLSeiN9c.html) de Termium, banque de terminologie du gouvernement du Canada, fait cette distinction en précisant que l'usage de *tout d'un coup* au sens de *tout à coup* relève de la langue littéraire ou de la langue familière de certaines régions du Canada.

Cependant, le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coup), sous l'entrée *coup*, bien qu'il donne le même sens que que Termium pour *tout à coup*, indique que la définition « d'un seul coup » de *tout d'un coup* est vieillie et ajoute la définition « brusquement ».

On peut donc considérer que les deux usages sont corrects, mais la locution *tout à coup* est probablement la plus courante.